# c# List<T>, получить item не по индексу,а по значению

Tags: c#

Есть самописный класс

```
public class SectionClass
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Comment {get; set; }
 ...
 public string Value {get;set;} 
}
```

Есть список `List<SectionClass> MyList`. В нем можно получить объект из списка по индексу

```
SectionClass section = MyList[2]
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, что-бы можно было получать объект по свойству, вот так

```
SectionClass section = MyList["Секция 1"]
```

Comment: Что значит получить объект по значению? SectionClass это же не строка о_О имеете ввиду по какому-то свойству вроде `section.Name`? Тогда например так `MyList.FirtOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Секция 1");`

Comment: @yolosora да. Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет о самописной коллекции, то вы можете объявить свой [индексатор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), а за "кулисами" делать все, что душе угодно, например видимость того, что массив индексируется не с 0, а с 1, а можете как вы хотите сделать индексацию по строке.

Например, так:

```
public class Reports
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string> queries;

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.queries[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никак, `List<T>` предоставляет к элементам доступ **только** по индексу.

Если нужен доступ по какому-то ключу, стоит вместо списка использовать [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Либо воспользоваться поиском, например с помощью метода [`Find`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Find_System_Predicate__0__)

Либо с помощью Linq, например метод [`First`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, SectionClass> MyList = Dictionary<string, SectionClass>();
```